# How to create over 60,00,000 edges in seconds in OrientDB

Tags: node.js, filestream, orientdb, readline, orientjs

I want to create over 60,00,000 edges in few minutes(within 30 minutes) in OrientDB. Is it Possible ??

values for each edge is taking from a text file and using Node JS filestream's readline (used version Node 4.x.x LTS version)

I have tried from Node.js using OrientJS driver and using batch;..batch of Queries ended by ;..commit.

It takes almost 3 hr and 30 min to complete it.

Comment: Hi, have you tried with Java? could be useful for you?

Comment: You should try something to read text files faster, thats for sure your bottleneck, read the entire file in one time, read line by line is too slow, after read the entire file, you could use some childs so you make requests parallelly.

Comment: No. I have to do it with Node JS

Comment: For the beginning, read the file in one step with fs.readFile, it will speed your process a lot.

Comment: @anijit Can you share the code ?

Comment: orientdb says it build for such type(one of yours) but I too never had a great performance.

It took around 3 hrs for me to create 9k vertex, edges and then it gave heap error at -xmx512M heap size

Comment: @PCP Yes, I have got that HEAP error thing sometimes.